# Java (Android) XML SAX is not parsing correctly

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, sax

I am developing an app where it takes its data from remote data source in XML format.

My app will then parse the XML into Objects so that the data can be put in the appropriate field.

Below is the XML source of my data (non essential parts are omitted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <opensearch:Query searchTerms="36557"/>
  <opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults>
  <movies>
    <movie>
      <popularity>95126.637</popularity>
      <translated>true</translated>
      <adult>false</adult>
      <language>en</language>
      <original_name>Casino Royale</original_name>
      <name>Casino Royale</name>
      <alternative_name>James Bond - 2006 - Casino Royale</alternative_name>
      <type>movie</type>
      <id>36557</id>
      <imdb_id>tt0381061</imdb_id>
      <url>http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/36557</url>
      <overview>James Bond goes on his first ever mission as a 00. Le Chiffre is a banker to the world's terrorists. He is participating in a poker game at Montenegro, where he must win back his money, in order to stay safe among the terrorist market. The boss of MI6, known simply as M sends Bond, along with Vesper Lynd to attend this game and prevent Le Chiffre from winning. Bond, using help from Felix Leiter, Mathis and having Vesper pose as his wife, enters the most important poker game in his already dangerous career. But if Bond defeats Le Chiffre, will he and Vesper Lynd remain safe?</overview>
      <votes>1325</votes>
      <rating>6.7</rating>
      <tagline>Everyone has a past. Every legend has a beginning.</tagline>
      <certification>PG-13</certification>
      <released>2006-11-17</released>
      <runtime>144</runtime>
      <budget>150000000</budget>
      <revenue>594786758</revenue>
      <homepage>http://www.mgm.com/view/movie/233/Casino-Royale-(2006)/</homepage>
      <trailer>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36mnx8dBbGE</trailer>
      <categories>
        .... OMITTED ....
      </categories>
      <keywords>
        .... OMITTED ....
      </keywords>
      <studios>
        .... OMITTED ....
      </studios>
      <languages_spoken>
        <language_spoken code="en" name="English" native_name="English"/>
        <language_spoken code="fr" name="French" native_name="Français"/>
      </languages_spoken>
      <countries>
        .... OMITTED ....
      </countries>
      <images>
        .... OMITTED ....
      </images>
      <cast>
        .... OMITTED ...
      </cast>
      <version>2595</version>
      <last_modified_at>2013-08-22 00:56:17 UTC</last_modified_at>
    </movie>
  </movies>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

My SAX parse the XML correctly i can retrieve all xml elements correctly but one element which is trailer element.

This is my java code

```
public class MovieDetailHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

private ArrayList<Movie> movieList;
private Movie movie;

private ArrayList<Image> movieImagesList;
private Image movieImage;

private ArrayList<String> movieCastList;
private String movieCast;

@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
        String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

    buffer.setLength(0);

    if (localName.equals("movies")) {
        movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("movie")) {
        movie = new Movie();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("images")) {
        movieImagesList = new ArrayList<Image>();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("image")) {
        movieImage = new Image();
        movieImage.type = atts.getValue("type");
        movieImage.url = atts.getValue("url");
        movieImage.size = atts.getValue("size");
        movieImage.width = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("width"));
        movieImage.height = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("height"));
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("movie")) {
        movieList.add(movie);
    }
    else if (localName.equals("popularity")) { // Get Popularity information
        movie.popularity = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("translated")) { // Get Translated information
        movie.translated = Boolean.valueOf(buffer.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equals("adult")) { // Get Adult information
        movie.adult = Boolean.valueOf(buffer.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equals("language")) { // Get Language information
        movie.language = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("original_name")) { // Get Original Name information
        movie.originalName = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("name")) { // Get Title information
        movie.name = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("type")) { // Get Type information
        movie.type = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("id")) { // Get Movie ID information
        movie.id = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("imdb_id")) { // Get IMDB ID information
        movie.imdbId = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("url")) { // Get TMDB URL information
        movie.url = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("votes")) { // Get Votes information
        movie.votes = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("overview")) { // Get Overview information
        movie.overview = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("rating")) { // Get Rating information
        movie.rating = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("released")) { // Get Released Date information
        movie.released = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("runtime")) { // Get Runtime information
        movie.runtime = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("trailer")) { // Get Trailer information
        movie.trailer = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("version")) {
        movie.version = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("last_modified_at")) {
        movie.lastModifiedAt = buffer.toString();
    }
    else if (localName.equals("image")) {
        movieImagesList.add(movieImage);
    }   
    else if (localName.equals("images")) {
        movie.imagesList = movieImagesList;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
    buffer.append(ch, start, length);
}

public ArrayList<Movie> retrieveMovieList() {
    return movieList;
}
```

I already make sure and double check that i can retrieve the element just before the *trailer* element and after the *trailer* element like such:

```
else if (localName.equals("budget")) {
    movie.trailer = buffer.toString();
}
```

It just that everytime i tried to retrieve the trailer element i am unable to retrieve it.

Note:

My LogCat display the XML element correctly as i attached above (It can retrieve the XML value correctly).

Does anyone know why is this?

Comment: Not sure whats wrong. But debugging your code will always help. Try to debug your code by adding breakpoints in `startElement`, `characters` and `endElement` methods

Comment: Just a suggestion. In your trailer data, append a / manually to the end of the url, just like the home page url and see if it works. Maybe that causes a break in the end tag and the parser could be jumping to the next element..

Comment: @Arunkumar, will try that in a moment.

Comment: @Andro Selva, you mean like this buffer.toString() + "/" I'll try that to. At this point any suggestion are pretty much welcome.

Comment: I totallly don't get this. I can Toast the url, homepage correctly. But everytime i try to Toast trailer i dont get anything. @AndroSelva appending "/" does not seem to work.

Comment: did you add the "/" manually in the xml itself?

Comment: @AndroSelva i am not sure by manually adding the "/" since the xml data is on some remote location. Hence i cannot modify the value directly. But, think of it this way, the url element does not have "/" ending trails yet i still able to retrieve its content correctly.

Comment: It appears that there is inconsistency with the API result. The result of executing http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getInfo/LAN/xml/API_KEY/MOVIE_ID

from browser differ with those from logcat. Still troubleshooting why..